# Watson Discovery Service - File size limit

Tags: watson-discovery

The Watson discovery service documentation says limit of file "The maximum file size that can be uploaded to the Discovery service is 50MB." But it seems there is a character limit as well which is 50000 characters.
The warning message is "Text content exceeds 50000 character limit. Only first 50000 characters processed...".
Can anyone please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

The warning about exceeding 50,000 characters is talking about enrichments. The text of entire document is still added to your Discovery collection, but the enrichments only apply to the first 50,000 characters of the document text.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Actually I need to extract all the entities from a certain paragraph which is beyond the 50000 characters. I will try by dividing the document into smaller documents.